# Microsoft Visual Basic Error

Tags: linked-tables, access-data-project

I have a table in an access database that keeps giving my a run-time error '3044' 'Y:\InfoSystem\CommData.mdb is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides. I don't understand why I am getting this error because the information should be coming from my C: drive and not the Y: I haven't changed anything to make it occur. Is there a way to change it to the C: drive? I believe it is a linked table.

Answer (score 0):

you have somewhere in your code a connection string that tells vb when to find the db. make sure that the path is right. try to search the whole project for "CommData.mdb"

it should be something like that:

```
Connection1.ConnectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & App.Path & "\CommData.mdb" & ";Persist security Info=False"
```

another approach is to try to set the path manually in your code